# Retrieve facebook posts using the javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have setup the JS SDK for facebook and can perform login and retrieve simple details like `name`.

```
FB.api('/me/', function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
```

I want to retrieve my posts during a certain time period. I used the [Facebook Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/) with `/me/posts` and I was able to retrieve the information I needed.

However when I call the JS API as the following, I get an empty response.

```
FB.api('/me/posts', {fields: 'data'}, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
```

How do I retrieve my posts. Also, if there is a way to retrieve the posts only within a time range (2 unix timestamps), that would be great.

Comment: Does the access token have user_posts permission?

Comment: why the "data" field?